# Only show button for specific items in multi select list

Tags: knockout.js

I have two multi select lists where you can copy items to eachother if it already doesn't exist in that list. The problem is that the copy button is visible all the time. 
I only want the button to be visible when you select items that doesn't exist in the other list (compared by the names).

Is this possible somehow?

Code:

```
var SProcsViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.storedProceduresInDB1 = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedStoredProceduresInDB1 = ko.observableArray();
    self.storedProceduresInDB2 = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedStoredProceduresInDB2 = ko.observableArray();

    self.copyToDb2 = function () {
        var sprocs = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedStoredProceduresInDb1(), function (value) {
            var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.storedProceduresInDB2(), function (item) {
                return value.Id === item.Id;
            });
            if (!match) {
                sprocs.push(value);
            } else {
                console.log('Match found for:', value);
            }
        });

        ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.storedProceduresInDB2, sprocs);
    };

    populateStoredProceduresInDbB1();
    populateStoredProceduresInDbB2();    

function populateStoredProceduresInDbB1 () {
    var array = [{
        Name: "Sp1",
        Id: 1,
        copyAllowed: false
        }, {
        Name: "Sp2",
        Id: 2,
        copyAllowed: false
        }, {
        Name: "Sp3",
        Id: 3,
        copyAllowed: true
        }, {
        Name: "Sp4",
        Id: 4,
        copyAllowed: true
    }];

    self.storedProceduresInDB1(array);
};

function populateStoredProceduresInDbB2 () {
    var array = [{
        Name: "Sp1",
        Id: 1,
        copyAllowed: false
        }, {
        Name: "Sp2",
        Id: 2,
        copyAllowed: false
        }, {
        Name: "Sp7",
        Id: 7,
        copyAllowed: true
        }, {
        Name: "Sp8",
        Id: 8,
        copyAllowed: true
    }];

    self.storedProceduresInDB2(array);
};

    return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new SProcsViewModel());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zp5K/42/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function to determine whether the 'Copy to DB2' button has to be visible:

```
self.notExistsInDb2 = function()
{
    if (!self.selectedStoredProceduresInDB1().length)
        return true;

    var chosenNames = self.selectedStoredProceduresInDB1().map(function(i) { return i.Name; });
    var existingNames = self.storedProceduresInDB2().map(function(i) { return i.Name; });

    for (var i in chosenNames)
        if (existingNames.indexOf(chosenNames[i]) > -1) return false;

    return true;
};
```

Then:

```
<button data-bind="click: copyToDb2, visible: notExistsInDb2()">Copy to DB2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The button appear/disappear now, but if i use this code i will not be able to copy items to the other list.

Comment: It has nothing to do with my code, your original Fiddle doesn't add to the list either. see http://jsfiddle.net/7zp5K/42/

Comment: I need to compare by the name and not the id's. Because they will always have unique id:s in the real database. And then this will not work. http://jsfiddle.net/7zp5K/45/

Comment: I changed it accordingly.